# apt-key command works on shell but fails on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gnupg, tty, apt-key

The following command seems to work when running it in a shell

```bash
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
            --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

but fails when executed in a `Dockerfile` as follows:

> Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
> Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1CIuj3LUOP/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
> gpg: cannot open '/dev/tty': No such device or address

The specific `RUN` command is executed in a `openjdk:8` image which in turn draws from `buildpack-deps:stretch-scm`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved by adding `--no-tty` on the `apt-key adv` command.

Any idea however why this was happening?

Comment: I think this might be related to this: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/526

Comment: I believe they fixed it also with the --batch option https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/922

Comment: I recently stumbled across the a similar issue (only with a different error message) and had to ressort to a combination of `--no-tty` **and** `--batch` to make it work.